# How to create page simlar to Person.aspx

Tags: user-profile, active-directory

We currently provide an email signature creator that employees can either use or not. The form asks users to enter information that we have in Active Directory. So, I was wondering if somebody can tell me how to create a page that prepopulates the info from AD into the form. Or, what I need to google for that might explain what it takes to implement this.

Thanks!

Yeah, I am extremely new to SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have synchronized the AD content to SharePoint you can easily create signature templates in SharePoint based on the info on the individuals User Profile. Create a new page and code it to use the current users User Profile information formated according to the corporate standard.

Start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee580299.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking at [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that you can use to get user profile from AD as well as user profile properties.

[Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637486/how-to-get-the-current-users-active-directory-details-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks how to add a page like Person.aspx.  If you wanted the signature template form to be a tab within the MySites/User Profile, then I have a blog post that explains how to add a tab to the standard navigation as well as a base Application Page that can be used to host the content.

You can find the full article and source code here:  http://www.mikeoryszak.com/sharepoint/user-profiles-adding-a-custom-tab-and-page